# Forbidden: 403 Access Denied error from GCP cloud

Tags: http-status-code-403

Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table marketcheck-gcp:marketcheck_histrorical_data.marketcheck_data: User does not have permission to query table marketcheck-gcp:marketcheck_histrorical_data.marketcheck_data.

Answer (score 0):

403 has to do with your authentification being forbidden. You have to make sure that 1/ you have allowed the user (you) to access GCP ressource in firebase and 2/ That you send a request with headers containing your accurate key or bearer token.